# Jasper report export to RTF not working correctly

Tags: jasper-reports, rtf

I am using jrxml to export to RTF format.
When number of columns are 12 it is working fine otherwise if we increase number of columns view seems distorted.

When I exported with 10 columns it looks perfectly fine.

I am new to this could anyone help me in this case.

jrxml template used:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="PSDefaultPointAndClick" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
 <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
 <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
 <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.4641000000000006"/>
 <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
 <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
 <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
 <import value="java.util.*"/>
 <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
 <parameter name="system.REPORT_NAME" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Default Report"]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="config.SUPPORTED_FORMATS" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["HTML,PDF,EXCEL,EXCEL_2007,RTF,CSV,POWERPOINT_2007"]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="config.FOR_INTERNAL_USE" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
 <parameter name="system.REPORT_FOOTER" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Copyright (c) 2007,"]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="config.DATASOURCE" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["PointAndClick"]]></defaultValueExpression>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="system.RUN_BY_AND_ON_INFO" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
 <parameter name="system.GENERATION_DATE" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
 <parameter name="system.USER_NAME" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
 <parameter name="system.PAGE" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
 <parameter name="system.EXPORT_FORMAT" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
 <field name="work_id" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <field name="owner" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <field name="owner_id" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <field name="status_current" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <field name="active_gate" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <field name="active_gate_id" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <group name="level1">
  <groupExpression><![CDATA[]]></groupExpression>
  <groupHeader>
   <band height="16" splitType="Prevent">
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
     <reportElement key="textField-12" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="54" y="0" width="341" height="16" backcolor="#EBEBEB"/>
     <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="2">
      <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
      <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
      <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
      <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
      <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     </box>
     <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
      <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" size="9"/>
     </textElement>
     <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Group Level 1 "]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
   </band>
  </groupHeader>
  <groupFooter>
   <band height="20" splitType="Prevent">
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
     <reportElement key="textField-22" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="395" height="16" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
     <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="2">
      <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
      <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
      <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
      <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
      <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     </box>
     <textElement>
      <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" isItalic="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" size="9"/>
     </textElement>
     <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Summary Level 1 "]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
   </band>
  </groupFooter>
 </group>
 <group name="level2">
  <groupExpression><![CDATA[]]></groupExpression>
  <groupHeader>
   <band height="16" splitType="Prevent">
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
     <reportElement key="textField-13" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="99" y="0" width="296" height="16" backcolor="#EBEBEB"/>
     <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="2">
      <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
      <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
      <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
      <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
      <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     </box>
     <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
      <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" size="9"/>
     </textElement>
     <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Group Level 2 "]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
   </band>
  </groupHeader>
  <groupFooter>
   <band height="20" splitType="Prevent">
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
     <reportElement key="textField-21" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="395" height="16" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
     <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="2">
      <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
      <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
      <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
      <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
      <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     </box>
     <textElement>
      <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" size="9"/>
     </textElement>
     <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Summary Level 2 "]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
   </band>
  </groupFooter>
 </group>
 <group name="level3">
  <groupExpression><![CDATA[]]></groupExpression>
  <groupHeader>
   <band height="16" splitType="Prevent">
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
     <reportElement key="textField-14" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="158" y="0" width="237" height="16" backcolor="#EBEBEB"/>
     <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="2">
      <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
      <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
      <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
      <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
      <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     </box>
     <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
      <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" size="9"/>
     </textElement>
     <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Group Level 3 "]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
   </band>
  </groupHeader>
  <groupFooter>
   <band height="20" splitType="Prevent">
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
     <reportElement key="textField-20" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="395" height="16"/>
     <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="2">
      <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
      <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
      <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
      <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
      <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     </box>
     <textElement>
      <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" size="9"/>
     </textElement>
     <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Summary Level 3 "]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
   </band>
  </groupFooter>
 </group>
 <background>
  <band splitType="Stretch"/>
 </background>
 <title>
  <band splitType="Stretch"/>
 </title>
 <pageHeader>
  <band splitType="Stretch"/>
 </pageHeader>
 <columnHeader>
  <band height="16" splitType="Prevent">
   <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement key="textField-4" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="395" height="16" backcolor="#E7EFF7"/>
    <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="2">
     <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
     <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
     <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </box>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
     <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["ColumnTitle"]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
  </band>
 </columnHeader>
 <detail>
  <band height="16" splitType="Prevent">
   <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement key="textField-11" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="235" y="0" width="160" height="16"/>
    <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="2"/>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="Arial" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Even_Row"]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement key="textField-16" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="395" y="0" width="140" height="16" backcolor="#FCFAF6"/>
    <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="2"/>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="Arial" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Odd_Row"]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
  </band>
 </detail>
 <columnFooter>
  <band height="20" splitType="Prevent">
   <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement key="textField-17" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="395" height="16"/>
    <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="2">
     <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
     <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
     <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
    </box>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Column Summary"]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
  </band>
 </columnFooter>
 <pageFooter>
  <band height="42" splitType="Prevent">
   <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement key="textField-26" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="6" width="58" height="36" backcolor="#F5F5F5"/>
    <box topPadding="3" bottomPadding="2">
     <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
     <font fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="Helvetica" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{system.PAGE} + " " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " /"]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement key="textField-27" mode="Opaque" x="58" y="6" width="59" height="36" backcolor="#F5F5F5"/>
    <box topPadding="3" bottomPadding="2">
     <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
     <font fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="Helvetica" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["" + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement key="textField-28" mode="Opaque" x="117" y="6" width="418" height="36" backcolor="#F5F5F5"/>
    <box topPadding="3" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="9">
     <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
     <font fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="Helvetica" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{system.REPORT_FOOTER}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
  </band>
 </pageFooter>
 <lastPageFooter>
  <band height="38" splitType="Stretch">
   <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement key="textField-23" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="2" width="58" height="36" backcolor="#F5F5F5"/>
    <box topPadding="3" bottomPadding="2">
     <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
     <font fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="Helvetica" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{system.PAGE} + " " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " /"]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement key="textField-24" mode="Opaque" x="58" y="2" width="59" height="36" backcolor="#F5F5F5"/>
    <box topPadding="3" bottomPadding="2">
     <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
     <font fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="Helvetica" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["" + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement key="textField-25" mode="Opaque" x="117" y="2" width="418" height="36" backcolor="#F5F5F5"/>
    <box topPadding="3" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="9">
     <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
     <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
     <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
     <font fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="Helvetica" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{system.REPORT_FOOTER}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
  </band>
 </lastPageFooter>
 <summary>
  <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
   <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement key="textField-18" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="535" height="16"/>
    <box>
     <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
     <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </box>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Root Summary"]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
  </band>
 </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

JRXML file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l866uv4z7sccf2c/12columns.jrxml?dl=0

[image: Screenshot after exporting to RTF]

Comment: What is wrong at your sample?

Comment: I have added 12 columns but only 6 columns are visible rest are not visible.

Comment: There are no 12 columns in your snippet

Comment: jrxml file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/l866uv4z7sccf2c/12columns.jrxml?dl=0

Comment: @AlexK added jrxml file also.. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an RTF document with a page size larger than 22 inch.
Your report template has a width of 23.11 inches.
The best explanation I could find is [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/95109).